# Evaluating $\int_\gamma |z|\,|dz|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm updating my question to reflect changes that have occurred.

I'm kind of stuck trying to figure out this integral:

$$\int_\gamma |z|\,|dz|=\int_{0}^{\pi}|t||1+t||dt|$$

where $\gamma(t)=te^{it}$ where $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

Since I have reduced this to $t$, do I approach this for $-t$ and $t$?

Comment: I am trying to work out what $z$ is as a function of $t$. I have tried $z = te^{it}$ and $z = t^2e^{it}$ but neither of them is right. I don't want to misunderstand the question. Do you have any further information?

Comment: Sorry, there is $\gamma(t)=te^{it}$ with $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

Comment: I still don't understand.  What's the function that you're integrating over?

Comment: I've added that to the question.

Comment: Check the derivation of |dz|.

Comment: How did you do the differentials' equivalence?:$$z=te^{it}\implies dz=\left(e^{it}+tie^{it}\right)dt\implies |dz|=|1+ti||dt|$$

Comment: Well $|it^2e^{it}|=|it^2|=t^2$.

Comment: What has that to do with the differentials, @Morris ?

Comment: @Morris: see DonAntonio's comment.

Comment: It seems that I have forgotten about the product rule.

Comment: Here is a trick for evaluating $|dz|$ integrals in general: Use algebraic manipulation to write $|dz|$ in terms of $dz$, at which point the residue theorem becomes available to you.

Comment: I'm not far enough in the course to know the residue theorem.  I'm trying to evaluate these contour integrals by hand to get the hang of it.

Comment: @Manyfolds: the residue theorem is of little use here; any manipulations of the integral to make it useful involve making the problem way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the question as asking for

$$I = \int_\gamma |z| |dz|$$

where the curve $\gamma$ is defined to be the locus of $z(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=\pi$ with $z(t) = t e^{it}$.

Then $|z| = t$ and $|dz| = |e^{it} + ite^{it}| = |1+it| = \sqrt{1+t^2}$, so

$$\begin{eqnarray}
I & = & \int_0^\pi t\sqrt{1+t^2} dt \\
  & = & \frac12 \int_{t=0}^{t=\pi} \sqrt{1+t^2}d(1+t^2) \\
  & = & \frac13 \left[(1+t^2)^\frac32\right]_{t=0}^{t=\pi} \\
  & = & \frac{(1+\pi^2)^\frac32 - 1}{3} \\
  & = & 11.612\dots
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\int_\gamma |f(z) \, dz|=\int_a^b|f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)|\,dt$$

Hence

$$\int_\gamma | dz|=\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$$

Which is the length of the curve $\gamma$.